# Building a jar with the res folder using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using Slick2D to create a very simple game to share with my friends. However I am having trouble packaging the JAR file. The JAR build completes, I try to run the JAR and it crashes. After running it with command prompt, I got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource Not found ./src/res/playbutton.png`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.thirdspare</groupId>
<artifactId>zurvive</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.thirdspare.zurvive.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/res</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there something I am missing from my pom.xml file? I have tried a few different things to try and get it to all build together, and I am just wondering if I've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not files but entries on the classpath.  You should use exactly the name it has in the jar file.

In your case that would be `/playbutton.png` or `playbutton.png` depending on your usage.

Comment: It's not being put into the jar file, only my classes are when I package it. How do I get them to package with the classes? Preferably in a separate directory that follows the current pathway.

Comment: Maven does this automatically for `src/main/resources` for Java projects.

Comment: I moved all of my resources over to src/main/resources, it has finally packaged them into the jar after changing my pom.xml, and changing my usages to just `playbutton.png` But what if I wanted to have them in a directory inside of the jar, such as resources. As of right now it is just sitting in the root of the JAR file.

Comment: Put them in `src/main/resources/resources`.  Adjust your lookup name accordingly.